# What is the name of the feature shown in the screenshot below?

Tags: thumb

The area in white can be scrolled up for easy access to different features, and reveal more content.

[image]

Comment: I call it a "drawer".

Answer (score 3):

This is referred to in the Apple Interface Guidelines as a **[Sheet](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/presentation/sheets)**

From iOS developer guidelines:

> A **sheet** helps people perform a scoped task that’s closely related to their current context.

The example you refer to above is a large sheet, and Apple's developer site provides some guidelines when to use.

This example includes the 'Grabber' so users can resize as well.

A simpler version of this UI is **[action sheets](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/presentation/action-sheets)**, mostly reserved for a couple of actions.